# Sex in diploid cones in gymnosperms

Tags: trees

Gymnosperms have male and female cones. If the cones are diploid, how can individual cones be male or female?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: In addition, can you answer this if you replace gymnosperms with animals and cones with genitalia? If so, then do you really have a question?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, you're right, I didn't think of it that way. I did many searches and thought about it a couple of days. But guess what -- no one explains patently obviously things. I was being silly, as you noted. I mean I still had a question and I'm glad I asked and your rude response makes me glad I also didn't make an account.

Comment: I'm sorry you found this rude, but perhaps you are being oversensitive? This site has standards that your question did not meet. You did not bother to take the (very short) tour to familiarize yourself with those standards and yet I took the time to let you know how you could do better and to give you (an apparently) useful hint as too where your thinking had gone wrong. If this level of feedback bothers you I suspect you will not be happy using Stack Exchange sites ...

Answer (score 1):

Being diploid or haploid isn't really related to which sex organs are produced by a plant. As you say, many gymnosperms (and angiosperms) produce both male and female cones on a single plant. [image: A forked Pinus contorta branch on a white background, with male one one side of the fork and female cones the other]

Development of these cones would be caused by genes carried in all of the plant's cells, but expressed differently in different locations.

Some gymnosperms (and angiosperms) are dioecious, meaning they have different sex organs on different individuals (i.e., male and female individuals).

[image: Ginko biloba branch with male pollen cones on a black background, with the male Mars symbol in blue in the upper left][image: Ginko biloba branch with female ovules on a black background, with the female Venus symbol in red in the upper right]

Here, still, the sex determination is not related to ploidy. The sex determination could be caused by several mechanisms, depending on the species, including a [single gene](https://doi.org/10.3389/fpls.2020.01162), or a variety of [sex chromosome](https://doi.org/10.1007/s12041-014-0326-7) combinations.